# Is there a way to deliver only House Ads through AdMob?

Tags: android, ios, admob, ads

I'm creating an iOS / Android app where I'd like to utilize AdMob to deliver house ads. However I do not want to display any other ad networks, only my house ads. Is there a way to disable 'ad sources ordered by eCPM'?

Answer (score 1):

I think [DoubleClick For Publishers](https://www.google.com/dfp) is much easier for this scenario.

But when using Admob, you can select the countries to use for the "Admob Network". You can select a single country, that will be very unlikely to use your app. And disable delivery to other countries.

Comment: Finally a solution - it works with the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

Its there go to promote and down you can see how to create that house campaign...

[image]